# caml query to get events that occur next day

Tags: sharepoint-designer, caml-query, sharepoint-calendar, timer-jobs

I am creating a timer job for SharePoint 2016 on premise calendar event task. The function is to send reminder email to event attendees 1 day prior to event occurrence. I am creating a timer job to fetch the event attendees list (start time-date time field(need only date)) which is going to occur on next day and send email to attendees.

I created a CAML query to fetch the attendees who has events the next day in order to send email reminder 1 day prior but it is not working.

Using VS to create the timer job.

Can you please help me out?
[image: screenshot of list]

My query:

```
sPQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Start_x0020_Time\" /><Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type=\"DateTime\"><Today OffsetDays = 1/></Value></Eq></Where>";
```

Comment: Are you using default calendar list or you are using custom list here?

Comment: default calendar list. and also created a new attendees list to save the attendees and events data from calendar list

Comment: actually this query fetches data from attendees list

Comment: sPQuery.Query = "<WHERE><Eq><FieldRef Name = \"Start_x0020_Time\" />< Value Type = \"DateTime\"><Today Offset = \"1\" /></ Value ></Eq></WHERE >";

Comment: tried the above but it fetches all list items

Comment: Please share you list details from where you want to query data. You can add screen shot of your list here

Comment: screenshot added to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are missing double quote in OffsetDays attribute under Today element

Try below query and it should work:

```
sPQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Start_x0020_Time\" /><Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type=\"DateTime\"><Today OffsetDays=\"1\"/></Value></Eq></Where>";
```